pd.to_datetime() not consistently working to convert objects
I have been working with this data (csv) that exists in an AWS S3 bucket. When I am pulling the data I have to transform all the columns to their correct dtypes.
All other dtypes are working properly but datetime64 types.
In the first image below - I am printing the provider_dob which is the desired format, datetime64

However, I have printed the dtypes later down in my code and says that it is an object now?
Below is my snippet of code.

I am not sure how to rationalize this and need a second set of eyes.

And what is df['last_modified_date'] showing as a type?

I would suggest using text formatting to show your code rather than screenshots, and providing a reproducible example

@roganjosh it was an object too. Sorry for the screenshots but its what I had at the moment.

I believe that the issue is your df.replace() call. That is the only transformation that you seem to be applying to the dataframe as a whole and thus touching your dob column.
If you look elsewhere, you will notice that this transformation can change data types to object.
The solution is given in that linked question:

I've come across this many times, and there is a fix. precede your usage of your replace with astype(object) and it will preserve the dtypes.


Perfect! This solved my issue. Thank you so much! Didn't know it could have been from the df.replace() function. Cheers!
